# C++ operator overloading cheatsheet

Tags: c++

Does anyone have a summary of boilerplate declarations for C++ operator overloading?  A one page pdf would be nice.  It would help us forgetful people having to stop and think about where to put our `const` and `&` and `friend` etc.

Comment: +1 it might also help self learners (like me) not going crazy (yep, just like me ;) )

Comment: understanding is almost always better than copying.

Comment: Understanding and productivity aids aren't mutual exclusive.

Comment: You should just read this, and learn the ins and outs of them.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html

Comment: @Duck The point was with understanding the reference is no longer needed. Cheatsheets and google are fine for rarely used algorithms but when and why to use keywords such as `const` is something that should simply be known.

Comment: @AJG85 Agree that understanding should be first. Why isn't reference needed? Unless you have photographic memory...

Comment: @AJG85 - beyond the handful of common operators I would suggest most overloads do fall into the rarely used category for most people.  I have set up a few templates for these in my editors.  It doesn't relieve me of some copy & pasting nor thinking about the correctness of what I am inserting but it does eliminate some steps and starting from square one on things I may do once every six months.

Comment: @AJG85: I frequently use a list to make sure I didn't miss any.  There's been several times I'm making a number-like class and forgot `|=`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: I agree that's quite true for the less used operators. [This might be a useful reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia has a pretty nice entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Complete with prototypes for both member and global functions, where applicable.

Comment: That almost exactly what I was looking for.  Just need someone to condense it down to a handy document I can take on the road.  Might make one of my minions do it.  Any suggestions for a good place to host and share such a document?

Comment: Ironically, [Gary Buyn](http://stackoverflow.com/users/749517/gary-buyn) had an almost identical answer 6 minutes earlier which he deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Summary:

- Assignment and compound assignment operators must be members, not friends.
- Use the copy-and-swap idiom and pass-by-value for assignment operators.  This gives you exception safety and handles the "assign-to-self" case.
- Operators where the custom class can appear as either operand should be friends.

Comment: Not exactly what I was after, but you make some good points that should be included in a cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The SPARKCHARTS C++ reference sheet has a nice mini-summary of operator overloading. They were kind enough to put it up on the Web:

[C++ Operator Overloading](http://sparkcharts.sparknotes.com/cs/cplusplus/section14.php)

Comment: ...and they aren't using `const` right, so this really doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: Agreed. Const correctness is worth considering. How would you re-write the Sparkchart summary to include const correctness? (In fact, how would a C++ maven re-write the Sparkchart summary to be, in general, more useful?)